# Handling auto indent in Node.js REPL when copy pasting

Tags: javascript, node.js, readline, read-eval-print-loop

I need general idea how to solve my problem. I have REPL for LIPS my [Scheme based LISP in JavaScript](https://jcubic.github.io/lips/) and I have node.js REPL using readline. The last thing I need to solve is to fix double indent when I'm copy paste snippet of code that already have indent.

I have code like this:

```js
var highlight = require('../../prism-cli/index.js'); // temporary local copy
rl._writeToOutput = function _writeToOutput(stringToWrite) {
    rl.output.write(highlight(stringToWrite, 'scheme', true));
};
process.stdin.on('keypress', (c, k) => {
    setTimeout(function() {
        rl._refreshLine(); // force refresh colors
    }, 0);
});
boostrap(interp).then(function() {
    rl.on('line', function(line) {
        code += line + '\n';
        try {
            if (balanced_parenthesis(code)) {
                rl.pause();
                prev_eval = prev_eval.then(function() {
                    var result = run(code, interp);
                    code = '';
                    return result;
                }).then(function(result) {
                    if (process.stdin.isTTY) {
                        print(result);
                        if (newline) {
                            // readline don't work with not endend lines
                            // it ignore those so we end then ourselfs
                            process.stdout.write("\n");
                            newline = false;
                        }
                        if (multiline) {
                            rl.setPrompt(prompt);
                            multiline = false;
                        }
                        rl.prompt();
                    }
                    rl.resume();
                }).catch(function() {
                    if (process.stdin.isTTY) {
                        if (multiline) {
                            rl.setPrompt(prompt);
                            multiline = false;
                        }
                        rl.prompt();
                    }
                });
            } else {
                multiline = true;
                var ind = indent(code, 2, prompt.length - continuePrompt.length);
                rl.setPrompt(continuePrompt);
                rl.prompt();
                var spaces = new Array(ind + 1).join(' ');
                if (terminal) {
                    rl.write(spaces);
                } else {
                    process.stdout.write(spaces);
                    code += spaces;
                }
            }
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e.message);
            code = '';
            rl.prompt();
        }
    });
}).catch(function() {
    console.error('Internal Error: boostrap filed');
});
```

indent function calculate number of spaces that need to be added in next line, this works fine when I'm typing the code by hand but when I'm copy pasting code with indent I end up with double indent.

I'm seeking solution for fixing this issue, I'm fine with the solution that edit the text in terminal stdout and rewrite each line with removing the spaces after the text is entered. I can be after each line I can correct the previous line, but don't know how.

I would also like to know if there is a way to detect if there was space typed by the user (actual keypress).

I can't check if line have spaces at the beginning because the indent happen before actual line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem by patching previous line in terminal using ANSI codes one other fix is that I was able to syntax highlight the code on previous line that was not working when copy paste:

```
boostrap(interp).then(function() {
    rl.on('line', function(line) {
        code += line + '\n';
        var format, spaces, stdout;
        var lines = code.split('\n');
        // fix previous line
        if (lines.length > 1) {
            var prev_line = lines[lines.length - 2].replace(/^\s+/, '');
            if (lines.length > 2) {
                var prev = lines.slice(0, -2).join('\n');
                fs.appendFileSync('lips.log', prev + '\n');
                var i = indent(prev, 2, prompt.length - continuePrompt.length);
                spaces = new Array(i + 1).join(' ');
                lines[lines.length - 2] = spaces + prev_line;
                code = lines.join('\n');
                stdout = continuePrompt + spaces;
            } else {
                stdout = prompt;
            }
            stdout += highlight(prev_line, 'scheme', true);
            // ANSI Codes: 1F move to the begining of prev line
            //             K clear from cursor to the end of the line
            format = '\x1b[1F\x1b[K' + stdout + '\n';
            process.stdout.write(format);
        }
        try {
            // rest of the code
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e.message);
            code = '';
            rl.prompt();
        }
    });
}).catch(function() {
    console.error('Internal Error: boostrap filed');
});
```